# Making a blackout div stretch to 100% of the height of the div on top of it

Tags: html, css

I have a "blackout" div (a div that fills the entire screen with black on 50% opacity) to help create focus for a popup div that's on top of it.

I currently have the blackout div set to `height: auto` and `min-height` as 100 VH. It has `position: absolute`. The popup div is 600 px in height. The issue is, if the height of the browser window is smaller than the popup div height, the blackout div only stretches to the height of the browser window rather than the popup div.

**Normal:**

[image: Normal]

**Small browser window height, scrolled down:**

[image]

Comment: Give `positioned:fixed;` a try. `position:absolute;` is relative to the parent container and so is able to be moved with the scroll; `position:fixed;` says to stay put no matter the scroll position.

Comment: The issue with fixed is you can't scroll down to see the entire popup window. If the browser height is 400px I can't see the remaining 200px of the popup.

Comment: what about giving the background `position:fixed;` while giving the pop-up `position:absolute;`?

Comment: Move the "blackout" div outside of popup code and give it fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure `height:auto;` has an effect in this case.

Try :

```
.blackout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```